# F.relu(self.fc1(x)) is causing RuntimeError problem

Tags: python, pytorch

I have implemented the following CNN for my training and validation data sets
that contain 90 and 20 images respectively divided into 3 classes:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 50)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, len(classes))


def forward(self, x):
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    print(x.shape)
    x = x.view(x.size(0),-1)
        #x = x.view(-1,x.size(1)*x.size(2)*x.size(3))
        #x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

I am getting the following error while running:

```
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 214720], m2: [400 x 120] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2033 for x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
```

Can someone please suggest what I should do to get rid of this problem? I changed the x.view(...) by following some threads. However, it did not help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the `in_channels` to `self.fc1` is dependent on the input image size and not on the kernel-size.

In your case, 
`self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)` should be `nn.Linear(16 * image_size * image_size)`
where, `image_size`: is the size of the image in the last convolution layer.

Sample Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, classes):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5, padding=2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5, padding=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 25 * 25, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 50)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        print('one', x.shape)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        print('two', x.shape)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        print('three', x.shape)
        x = x.view(-1, np.product(x.shape[1:]))
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

x = torch.rand((32, 3, 100, 100))
net = Net(2)
out= net(x)
print('out', out.shape)
```

---

```
one torch.Size([32, 3, 100, 100])
two torch.Size([32, 6, 50, 50])
three torch.Size([32, 16, 25, 25])
out torch.Size([32, 2])
```

Comment: Hello srmsoumya
Thanks for your comment. It helps me to understand the problem. However,
I am getting another error when I calculate the loss between the output from the model and target:
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.
I have used nn.CrossEntropyLoss() and optim.SGD(model_scratch.parameters(), lr=0.01) as loss and optimizer

Comment: Hi @MahbuburRahman It might be an issue with the number of nodes in your final layer compared to the number of outputs, you can check this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-assertion-cur-target-0-cur-target-n-classes-failed/8034) if it helps or else if you could share the code I can probably take a look and suggest.

Comment: Hi @srmsoumya
Thanks for your quick reply. I changed according to the link that you provided. However, it did not work out. I pro<ipython-input-17-10af78c2782e> in train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criteriovided the code in the Sample code section. I am getting the following error:

---> 31             loss = criterion_scratch(output, target)
   
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @MahbuburRahman if you can open a new thread for this discussion with additional details it will be helpful for others as well :-)

Comment: Hi @srmsouyma
Thanks for you reply. I will do that. For a quick response,
I have uploaded the code in my github profile:
 https://www.github.com/shawonmr/DogBreedClassifier 
I am getting the RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed at the  loss = criterion_scratch(output, target) step in the 
classify.py file.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @srmsouyma
I have solved the problem by subtracting 1 from the target in DataLoader.
Thanks
Mahbubur Rahman